# How to disable built-in ErrorSummary in DataGrid?

Tags: datagrid, silverlight-5.0

I want to disable `ErrorSummary` in my `DataGrid`, but I cannot find a intuitive way to do it, can someone point me out how to do it?
Thanks
Elio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to disable the error summary. You'll have to apply a style to the DataGrid that doesn't include it. You can take the [default style on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and remove the [ValidationSummary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationsummary%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) element from the XAML.